# SQLite in java - I have only one table that seems too big?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an app that allows users to store an int value for 50 different symptoms once per day.  So in my SQLite db, my primary key is the symptom and the date (see below).

```
  String CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM = "CREATE TABLE " + Symptom.TABLE  + "("
            + Symptom.KEY_Symptom  + " INTEGER NOT NULL , "
            + Symptom.KEY_date + " INTEGER NOT NULL , "
            + Symptom.KEY_level + " INTEGER , "
            + "PRIMARY KEY ( " + Symptom.KEY_Symptom + " , " + Symptom.KEY_date + " ))";
```

My table with have 50 entries per day which is alot.
Is there a more efficient way of breaking up this table so I won't have so many entries?  I

Comment: "My table with have 50 entries per day which is alot" - not really, unless this is going to be on a *really* constrained device. What makes you concerned that 50 rows a day is going to prove too much?

Comment: I would imagine implementing searching algorithms later on (such as retrieving all entries by month or day or symptom) could be costly with tens of thousands of table entries.

Comment: Rather than *imagining*, why not perform actual tests? It should be easy enough to generate random data consistent with (say) 5 years of data, then check what the performance is like for the queries you're interested in. Given that the date and symptom are primary keys, both should be indexed so querying should be quick.

Comment: Why are you creating tables for each sympton? with 50 entries each that are small tables. Are there 50 symptons per day or 50 entries in one symtons table?

Comment: There are 50 symptoms per day.  I only have one table with 3 columns and 50 rows per day.